# improving functionality image combine matlab

Tags: image, matlab, concatenation

Here is the code i'm working with.  It demonstrates my end goal perfectly.  I want to improve upon this process so I can make a simple GUI interface later on.  I want to be able to target the specific photos in a loop determined by user input.  I will ask for a specific mode 1-5.  I think I'll keep the mode restriction to a range of picture combos of 4 8 12 16 and 20 pictures (1-5).  I then want to loop through the range and click on the specified amount of photos to add that and then combine.

1. What commands can I play with to be able to select photos from so that any file name will work?  I tried using things like uigetfile and uigetdir but was unsuccessful in using them to do what I needed.  A size restriction is ok but eventually I would like to overcome that.  All my photos are 604x453 to make life easy for now.
2. If you understand what I'm trying to do and have thoughts about doing it differently, I'm here to learn so enlighten me because I'm brand new to Matlab.  This is a learning experience to get a hang of matlab for me so any input is appreciated.

   ```
    %this is the code for my 3x3 currently
    p1 = double(imread('photo1.jpg'));
    p2 = double(imread('photo2.jpg'));
    p3 = double(imread('photo3.jpg'));
    p4 = double(imread('photo4.jpg'));
    p5 = double(imread('photo5.jpg'));
    p6 = double(imread('photo6.jpg'));
    p7 = double(imread('photo7.jpg'));
    p8 = double(imread('photo8.jpg'));
    p9 = double(imread('photo9.jpg'));


    h1conc = horzcat(p1, p2, p3);
    h2conc = horzcat(p4, p5, p6);
    h3conc = horzcat(p7, p8, p9);

    collage = vertcat(h1conc, h2conc, h3conc);
    figure,
    imagesc(uint8(collage));
   ```

Comment: Why is uigetfile unsuited for your needs? You may use a filter specification to display/hide specific file types. However, there is no need to do so. I do not know of any size restrictions, as uigetfile does not load the file.

Comment: I used a while loop to collect a mode from the user and then used a for loop with i =1:mode running through all the photos of the mode specified with name{i} = uigetfile('*.*');  I was unsure of where to go from there.  The size restriction comes from the commands hortcat and vertcat require symmetry and its easy just to resize everything to the same size.

Comment: I see - well, considering the post of Daniel R, all you need is to plug "name" into montage: montage(name).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [montage](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/images/ref/montage.html)

```
montage({'photo1.jpg','photo2.jpg','photo3.jpg'});
```

Comment: I'm looking at the help page for montage.  Thank you.  Looks like it will be really useful.